# How to get all environment variables inside the docker container using python script and cronjob?

Tags: python, linux, docker

I am learning Docker and I have query.
I am trying to fetch all environment variables which are currently present inside the Docker container through the python script and store the output into one file and this python file running periodically using cronjob.
Now the problem I am facing is I am not able to get all environment variables through my script.
suppose in the container if I export some Environment variable then my script should put this entry in the file but I can't?
My python code is

```py
import subprocess

def set_env():
    subprocess.getoutput('printenv > /home/enviornment_variable.txt')
    
set_env()
```

and this file run periodically run using cronjob. But couldn't fetch all environment variable.

Comment: The environment variables are in the [`os.environ`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.environ) object; you don't need to launch a subprocess for this.  Still, it seems like that script should work; what problem are you encountering?

Comment: @DavidMaze agree with your point os.environ gives environment variable but I am trying to run this python file using cronjob and as per my knowledge(may be wrong) cron create its own shell so, whenever I export the environment variable inside the container, using this python file I am not able to capture. So I want to know how can I do? So, periodically I am able to get those environment variable which I export